# JavaScript: How to reverse a number?

Tags: javascript

Below is my source code to reverse (as in a mirror) the given number.
I need to reverse the number using the reverse method of arrays.

```html
<script>
   
    var a = prompt("Enter a value");
    var b, sum = 0;
    var z = a;
    while(a > 0)
    {
      b = a % 10;
      sum = sum * 10 + b;
      a = parseInt(a / 10);
    }
    alert(sum);
</script>
```

Comment: you're collecting all the numbers into a sum so how are you supposed to reverse that? You mean reverse a single number like 123 becomes 321?

Comment: Do you mean you want to take input from user say 27 and then get the mirror inverted/reversed number 72 as the result?

Comment: The number being an item of an Array is irrelevant to this question

Answer (score 48):

### Low-level integer numbers reversing:

```js
function flipInt(n){
    var digit, result = 0

    while( n ){
        digit = n % 10  //  Get right-most digit. Ex. 123/10 → 12.3 → 3
        result = (result * 10) + digit  //  Ex. 123 → 1230 + 4 → 1234
        n = n/10|0  //  Remove right-most digit. Ex. 123 → 12.3 → 12
    }  
  
    return result
}


// Usage: 
alert(
  "Reversed number: " + flipInt( +prompt("Enter a value") ) 
)
```

The above code uses [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) for quick math

This method is ***MUCH FASTER*** than other methods which convert the number to an Array and then reverse it and join it again. This is a low-level blazing-fast solution.

#### Illustration table:

```js
const delay = (ms = 1000) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
const table = document.querySelector('tbody')

async function printLine(s1, s2, op){
  table.innerHTML += `<tr>
    <td>${s1}</td>
    <td>${s2||''}</td>
  </tr>`
}

async function steps(){
  printLine(123)
  await delay()
  
  printLine('12.3 →')
  await delay()
  
  printLine(12, 3)
  await delay()
  
  printLine('1.2', '3 &times; 10')
  await delay()
  
  printLine('1.2 →', 30)
  await delay()
  
  printLine(1, 32)
  await delay()
  
  printLine(1, '32 &times; 10')
  await delay()
  
  printLine('1 →', 320)
  await delay()
  
  printLine('', 321)
  await delay()
}

steps()
```

```css
table{ width: 200px; }
td {
  border: 1px dotted #999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Current</th>
      <th>Output</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why the bitwise OR operator in ```n = n/10|0``` ?

Comment: @verma Aman it is to remove the decimal value 321/10 will give 32.1 and we need only the number 32 and not the decimal

Comment: not working for 127.12  means for decimal numbers

Comment: @gunal - different cultures use different representations of floating point numbers, therefore I ignored floating point numbers and only reverse integer inputs

Comment: In my case, it is actually slower than using `n.toString().split("").reverse().join("")`

Answer (score 11):

Assuming @DominicTobias is correct, you can use this:

```js
console.log( 
    +prompt("Enter a value").split("").reverse().join("") 
)
```

Comment: What if the number is negative? -123 would equal to NaN

Comment: What would you like the result to be in that case?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? It should be `-321` :)

Comment: val < 0 ? -(Math.abs(val).split("").reverse().join("")) : +(val.split("").reverse().join(""));

Answer (score 4):

I was recently asked how to solve this problem and this was my initial solution:

---

> ***The desired output:*** *123 => 321, -15 => -51, 500 => 5*

```js
function revInt(num) {
// Use toString() to convert it into a String
// Use the split() method to return a new array: -123 => ['-', '1','2','3']
// Use the reverse() method to reverse the new created array: ['-', '1','2','3'] => ['3','2','1','-'];
// Use the join() method to join all elements of the array into a string
  let val = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
    // If the entered number was negative, then that '-' would be the last character in
   //  our newly created String, but we don't want that, instead what we want is
  //  for it to be the first one. So, this was the solution from the top of my head.

// The endsWith() method determines whether a string ends with the characters of a specified string
  if (val.endsWith('-')) {
    val = '-' + val;
      return parseInt(val);
  }
      return parseInt(val);
}

console.log(revInt(-123));
```

---

***A way better solution:***

After I gave it some more thought, I came up with the following:

```js
   // Here we're converting the result of the same functions used in the above example to 
// an Integer and multiplying it by the value returned from the Math.sign() function.

// NOTE: The Math.sign() function returns either a positive or negative +/- 1, 
// indicating the sign of a number passed into the argument.   

function reverseInt(n) {
      return parseInt(n.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) * Math.sign(n)
}

console.log(reverseInt(-123));
```

*NOTE: The 2nd solution is much more straightforward, IMHO*

Comment: Again this will fail with very large integers as JS will convert them to exponent notation in the `toString` operation. 10000000000000000000000000000647 becomes 1e+31, which reverses to 13+e1, which `parseInt`s to 13.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution, pure JS without predefined functions.

```js
function reverseNum(number) {
  var result = 0,
    counter = 0;
  for (i = number; i >= 1 - Number.EPSILON; i = i / 10 - (i % 10) * 0.1) {
    counter = i % 10;
    result = result * 10 + counter;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(reverseNum(547793));
```

Comment: Dont work for number having second last digit as 0 , for instance 1401

Comment: @ShyamTayal you are partial in right. it's not because the second digit is equal to zero, because 1202 is going to be reversed correctly. It's actually a JS behavior where 0.3 - 02 !== 0.1
And thank you for your comment, because I didn't know this. So to be precise, the problem is in the expression i = i / 10 - (i % 10) * 0.1) because it will not evaluate always to 1, which is mathematically expected, but in some cases, it will be the closest decimal number to number 1 (0.999999...).
So I will edit the code. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think you are using an array to store the number. You are using a java script variable.

Try out this code and see if it works.

```
var a = prompt("Enter a value");
var z = a;
var reverse = 0;
while(z > 0)
{
    var digit = z % 10;
    reverse = (reverse * 10) + digit;
    z = parseInt(z / 10);
}
alert("reverse = " + reverse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, as a one-liner ( `x` contains the integer number to be inversed):

```
revX=x.toFixed(0).split('').reverse().join('')-0;
```

The number will be separated into its individual digits, reversed and then reassembled again into a string. The `-0` then converts it into a number again.

Comment: Suffers from the big integer problem. (10000000000000000000000000000647).toFixed(0) returns 1e+31, which when split, reversed, and joined is 13+e1. If you `parseInt` it, you get 13. If you do `'13+e1' - 0` , you'll get `NaN`

Comment: Does any of the other methods _not_ "suffer from the big integer problem"?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to reverse any integer in js. Doesn't work with float.

```
const i2a = number.toString().split("");
const a2i = parseInt(i2a.reverse().join(""));
console.log(a2i);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Using the JavaScript `reverse()` array method you can reverse the order of the array elements.

### Code

```js
var a = prompt("Enter a value");
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = a.charAt(i);
}
arr.reverse();
alert(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you may want to reverse it as a true number and not a string try the following:

```
function reverseNumber(num){
    num = num + '';
        let reversedText = num.split('').reverse().join('');
        let reversedNumber = parseInt(reversedText, 10);
    console.log("reversed number: ", reversedNumber);
        return reversedNumber;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript reverse() and Math.sign() you can reverse a number both positive and negative numbers.

```
var enteredNum = prompt("Enter integer");

function reverseInteger(enteredNum) {
    const reveredNumber = enteredNum.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
    return parseInt(reveredNumber)*Math.sign(enteredNum);
}

alert(reverseInteger(enteredNum));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply logic of reversing number in paper and try, and you have to care about dividing because it gives float values. That's why we have to use `parseInt()`.

```js
function palindrome()
{
  var a = document.getElementById('str').value;
  var r=0 ,t=0;
  while(a>0){
          r=a%10;
          t=t*10+r;
          a=parseInt(a/10);
      }

  document.write(t);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="str"/>
    <input type="submit" onClick="palindrome()" />
<form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add( num:number){  //159
let d : number; 
let a : number =0;  
while(num > 0){    //159  15  1
    d = num % 10;  
    a = a * 10 + d;  //9  95   951
    num = Math.floor(num/10);  // 15  1  0
}
 return a;  //951
}
console.log(add(159));
```

Comment: Please try not to just provide a code snippet but also some details and explanation if possible as that would make for a clearer and most helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Reversing a number without converting it into the string using the recursive approach.

```js
const num = 4578;

const by10 = (num) => {
  return Math.floor(num / 10);
};
const remBy10 = (num) => {
  return Math.floor(num % 10);
};

const reverseNum = (num, str = "") => {
  if (num.toString().length == 1) return (str += num);
  return reverseNum(by10(num), (str += remBy10(num)));
};

console.log(reverseNum(num, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var reverse = function(x) {
    if (x > 2147483647 || x < -2147483648 || x === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    let isNegative = false;

    if(x < 0){
        isNegative = true;
        x = -x;
    }

    const length = parseInt(Math.log10(x));
    let final = 0;
    let digit = x;
    let mul = 0;

    for(let i = length ; i >= 0; i--){
        digit = parseInt(x / (10**i));
        mul = 10**(length-i);
        final = final + digit * mul; 
        x = parseInt(x % 10**i);
    }

    if (final > 2147483647 || final < -2147483648 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    if(isNegative){
        return -final;
    }
    else{
        return final;
    }
};

    
console.log(reverse(1534236469));
console.log(reverse(-123));
console.log(reverse(120));
console.log(reverse(0));
console.log(reverse(2,147,483,648));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseInt(n) {
    let x = n.toString();
    let y = '';

    for(let i of x) {
        y = i + y
    }
    return parseInt(y) * Math.sign(n);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sweet and simple:

```
function reverseNumber(num){
   return parseInt(num.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));
}
```

Comment: What are the errors can get in the future by using this function?

Answer (score -1):

The above code will not work for negative numbers. Instead, use the following:

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
    return  ((x>=0) ? ((x==(x = parseInt(x.toString().split("").reverse().join("")))) ? true:false) : false);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to

1. Covert it into a string and apply the  `reverse()` method
2. Change it back to number
3. Check for the value provided if negative or positive with **Math.sign()**

Below is my solution to that.

```js
function reverseInt(n) {
  const reversed =
    n.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
  return parseInt(reversed) * Math.sign(n);
}

console.log(reverseInt(12345));
```

Answer (score -2):

My solution to reverse a string:

```js
var text = ""
var i = 0
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]
var number = array.length
var arrayFinal = []

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    text = array[number - 1]
    arrayFinal.push(text)
    text = ""
  number = number - 1
}

console.log(arrayFinal)
```