# Write a JavaScript function that reverse a number

Tags: javascript

Result shows "n.split is not a function" unless i include n=n+" " the following code.What does third line mean?

```js
function reverse_a_number(n) 
{
  n = n + "";
  return n.split("").reverse().join("");
}
console.log(reverse_a_number(32243));
```

Comment: it convert a number to a string

Comment: The solution is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053729/javascript-how-to-reverse-a-number

Answer (score 4):

There is no `split` function in [`Number.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/prototype).  So, `n = n + ""` is just a simple way to convert a number to a string.

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)

> If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>   Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)

If one of the operands in an expression with `+` is a string, the other operand is also coerced to a string and concatenated with it

```js
console.log( 1 + 1 ) // sum
console.log( 1 + "1" ) // concatenation
console.log( true + "string" ) // concatenation
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no split function for Number. You can do this as an alternate

```
+String.prototype.split.call(32243,'').reverse().join('')
```

What the above code does?

1. I am using split method in String class via context switching for number which returns array.
2. Then we are reversing the number and joining it.
3. Then unary plus converts it to number.

As @briosheje mentioned, you can also use the following

```
+[...''+32243].reverse().join('')
```

Comment: You can avoid String.prototype by just doing: `''.split.call(target,'').reverse().join('')` or, even shorter: `[...''+32243].reverse().join('')`

Comment: I just wanted to try it in old school way, to just not to forget about the older implementation. Yeah. I agree with your solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
In javascript , there is no Explicit declaration of datatype, by assigning value to the variable , it implicitly takes the datatype like int,string.

In your case,Simple you are applying String function to integer , so you are getting Error.

So first convert integer value into String by using "toString()" function.

Solution:


function reverse_a_number(n) {
//Casting
n=n.toString();
  return Number(n.split("").reverse().join(""));
}
console.log(reverse_a_number(32243));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the number to a string and then use split as numerical values don't have the split function. Again cast it to a number while returning

```js
function reverse_a_number(n) {
n=n.toString();
  return Number(n.split("").reverse().join(""));
}
console.log(reverse_a_number(32243));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `split` method works only on string values and your passing integer value as argument, that's why it's working only after casting it to string

Answer (score 0):

You can't split a number. By using `n = n + ""`, you're casting it a string and then splitting it. However, you're also returning a string! You'll want to cast it back to an integer before you return it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. I think this could be solved easily.

1. turn the number to a string, this lets you turn it to an array
2. Split it to a array
3. use array's function 'reversed'
4. join it
5. turn it to an number or int again.

```js
const number = 3211232;
const numberReversed = parseInt(number.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));
console.log(numberReversed);
```