# Reverse a number without using reverse function

Tags: javascript, reverse

I need to reverse a number in JavaScript, but I don't know why the following code is entering into an infinite loop.

```
var num=1234;
var reverse=0;
while(num!=0) {
  reverse=reverse*10;            
  reverse=reverse+(num%10);
  num=num/10;
}
console.log(reverse);
```

I expect the output of 4321, but the actual output is an infinite loop

Comment: because 1234 / 10 = 123.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation `num = num / 10` needs to be an integer divide (otherwise `num` will take a very long time to become 0). Use [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) to strip any fractional part:

```
num=Math.trunc(num/10);
```

instead:

```js
var num = 1234;
var reverse = 0;
while(num !== 0){
  reverse = reverse*10;            
  reverse = reverse+(num%10);
  num = Math.trunc(num/10);
}
console.log(reverse);
```

Answer (score 1):

other method:

```js
var num = 1234
  , rev = 0
do {
  rev = (rev*10) + (num%10)
} while (num = Math.trunc(num/10))

console.log(rev)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
num=num/10;
```

To

```
num = num/10|0;
```

There are many ways to achieve this, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053729/javascript-how-to-reverse-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Math.trunc(x) to extract the whole number from the results of the division. or else you can use below methods as well.

Another method

```
var num = 1234;
var reverse = 0;
var final = 0;
while(num !== 0){
    reverse = num%10;
    num = parseInt(num/10);
    console.log(reverse);
    if(final! = '0'){
        final = final.toString().concat(reverse);
    }else {
        final = reverse;
    }
}
console.log(final);
```

or else even you can do something like this;

```
var num = 1234;
var reverse = num.toString().length;
var res = num.toString().charAt(1);
var final = "";

for(var i = reverse; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(num.toString().charAt(i));
    final = final.concat(num.toString().charAt(i))
}
console.log(final);
```