# Reverse Integer Without converting to a string Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So i am trying to reverse an integer and so far the code works but i am trying to find a solution to reverse the integer without converting into a string first? Any help would be appreciated. This is my code snippet so far to reverse the integer.

```
function reverseInt(num) {
    const reversed = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('')
    return parseInt(reversed) * Math.sign(num)
}

console.log(reverseInt(-500));
```

I am trying to do it using javascript.

Comment: How would you do that with pencil and paper?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher i believe i can use the `%` to check first. if i get it working, i'll post an answer. Actually this link does it quite well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053729/javascript-how-to-reverse-a-number

Comment: @NickMaroulis yup that same link did it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function reverseInt(number) {
    var isNegative = number < 0 ? true : false; 
    if(isNegative)
         number = number * -1; 
    var reverse = 0, lastDigit = 0; 
    while (number >= 1) {
         reverse = Math.floor(reverse * 10 + (number % 10)); 
         number = number / 10;
    } 
    return isNegative == true ? reverse*-1 : reverse;
}

console.log(reverseInt(-500));
console.log(reverseInt(501));
```